# How do I change the color of the status bar in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How can I change the color of the header section (status bar) in an iPhone App. The part with the carrier, time, and battery.

This part

[image]

More specifically, this part. I'd like to change the UI from black, to white or an easier to see color.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the text "Carrier" and the time, etc. or the background color of the status bar?

Comment: @rmaddy the text part, also knowing how to change just the background would be helpful too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the navigation bar color:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

To change the text in the navigation bar:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellowColor()]
```

Update
To change the status bar:

1. Go to your info.plist and add the following key `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set the value to `NO`
2. In you viewControllers viewDidload do set

White bar:
`UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent`

Dark bar:
`UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default`

Comment: Hey Rashwan, thanks so much for the help. So I'm kind of a newbie here. Where should I place this code? and do i need to link anything up to it?

Comment: Just add it in your `viewDidLoad` function @TrevorWood

Comment: I just put the code in there and this error came out... It's kind of long so I put it in my OP

Comment: Are you sure it´s because of the code above? I have created a [test project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TR9xoKqvZNa0Zzc2l2M0RocTQ/view?usp=sharing) for you that changes the navbar color and also the text. Take a look at it and see if you have done it like this.

Comment: yes I just made a completely new project and got this error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` Do I need to link anything up? I'll have a look at your example

Comment: ohhh, no I meant something different. I will post a new picture of what I'm trying to change

Comment: So you want to change the status bar. You can either have it white or black, check the update of how to change the color @TrevorWood